# Meaning of け after a テ形 verb

Tags: て-form

In some song lyrics I was reading it said 飛んでけ; and I was curious as to what the け meant. The translation just says leap out.

Answer (score 6):

It's a contraction of 飛んで行け. The い of 行く gets dropped fairly frequently after -て.

Comment: Not just the い of 行く, but also of いる, for example.